# IronPython - Exposing methods using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, ironpython

I'm using IronPython and I know how to expose methods from my class to the script's scope:

```
m_scope.SetVariable("log", new Action<string>(Log));

public void Log(string a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

However, instead of calling `SetVariable` everytime I want to speed up the process using reflection. So, I created an attribute called `ScriptMethodAttribute`:

```
public sealed class ScriptMethodAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ScriptMethodAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

That way, I can define methods inside my class for the script to use, like so:

```
[ScriptMethod("log")]
public void Log(string a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Now I want to call SetVariable on every method that uses this attribute to speed up the process. However, that doesn't seem to work.

This is a utility method that returns a list of `Tuple<ScriptMethodAttribute, MethodInfo`.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TAttribute, MethodInfo>> FindMethodsByAttribute<TAttribute>()
        where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    return (from method in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                    .Where(assembly => !assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache)
                    .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
                let attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(method, typeof(TAttribute), false) as TAttribute
                where attribute != null
                select new Tuple<TAttribute, MethodInfo>(attribute, method));
}
```

This is located in my script's class constructor:

```
foreach (var a in Reflector.FindMethodsByAttribute<ScriptMethodAttribute>())
{
    Action action = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), this, a.Item2);

    m_scope.SetVariable(a.Item1.Name, action);
}
```

I'm receiving the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is            not compatible with that of the delegate type.
```

I'm guessing it's because I have to include the required types in the Action constructor, but I don't know how to get them from the `MethodInfo` class.

Answer (score 0):

To handle methods with one parameter, you can use this code:

```
var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();

var delegateType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(parameters);

var action = methodInfo.CreateDelegate(delegateType, this);

// Now you can call m_scope.SetVariable with action
```

Things get more tricky if you want to handle methods with any number of parameters, because you need to add some branching depending on the number of elements in the `parameters` array. If there's two elements then you need to use `Action<,>` instead of `Action<>`, if there's three you need to use `Action<,,>`, and so on.

A not-so-elegant but quick way would be to preallocate an array with each type of Action:

```
private Type[] DelegateTypes = new[]
{
    typeof (Action),
    typeof (Action<>),
    typeof (Action<,>),
    typeof (Action<,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,,,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,,,,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,,,,,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,,,,,,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,,,,,,,,,,>),
    typeof (Action<,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,>)
};
```

From there, it's just a matter of accessing the right index of the array, depending on your number of parameters:

```
Type delegateType;

if (parameters.Length == 0)
    delegateType = DelegateTypes[0];
else
    delegateType = DelegateTypes[parameters.Length].MakeGenericType(parameters);
```

Comment: And what if my method require no parameters at all? Then how would I get the type? Also, is there a way to get the type based on the parameter count so I can extend this to any parameter count I want and not limit myself to one?

Comment: Ok, I see. That's what I was thinking about doing. Definitely not elegant but very smart.

Comment: When I'm trying to add an action that takes no parameters I'm getting an InvalidOperatioNException that is saying: System.Action is not a GenericTypeDefinition. MakeGenericType may only be called on a type for which Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition is true.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams Oh indeed, you need a special case when there's 0 parameters. Edited.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works flawlessly. I'll try to figure out a much simpler way to do this.